# Como colocar propriedades dentro de outra propriedade? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, propriedade, controles, toolbox

Eu gostava de saber como é que posso colocar propriedades dentro de uma outra propriedade, tal como no exemplo abaixo.

Exemplo:

[Propriedade Font Aberta/Expandida](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfZeg.png)

Eu tentei fazer muitas vezes de variadas formas, mas a mais aproximada que consegui foi a abaixo representada:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Design
Imports System.ComponentModel

Namespace ClassTest_ParentProperty

Public Class Class_Parent : Inherits Control
        Public Property MyProperties_Parent As Class_Child


        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class Class_Child
        Public Var_MyColor As Color = Color.Empty
        Public Var_MyText As New String(Nothing)
        Public Var_MySize As New Size(50, 50)

        Public Property MyColor As Color
            Get
                Return Var_MyColor
            End Get
            Set(value As Color)
                Var_MyColor = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property MyText As String
            Get
                Return Var_MyText
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                Var_MyText = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property MySize As Size
            Get
                Return Var_MySize
            End Get
            Set(value As Size)
                Var_MySize = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Mas com esta tentativa só consegui o que está abaixo representado:

[A propriedade que não se expande](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98m0E.png)

Eu procurei durante várias horas durante cerca de 3 dias, mas não encontrei o que eu queria.
Por isso espero que alguém me possa ensinar como posso fazê-lo.

Comment: Isso não parece ter sentido algum, provavelmente está partindo de uma premissa errada. A solução para o problema deve ser muito outra.

Comment: Eu não sei se me percebeu, mas eu pedi ajuda para saber como poderia fazer o que que queria, eu não disse que o código que coloquei estava certo. Caso estivesse não tinha feito o pedido de ajuda.

Comment: O que você quer não faz sentido. A não ser que não esteja explicado corretamente

Answer (score 1):

Coloque atributos de tipos do designer que vem da própria biblioteca .NET.

Referências:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
```

Declaração da classe `Class_Child`:

```
<Browsable(True)>
Public Class Class_Child
```

Declaração da propriedade:

```
<Browsable(True)>
<Description("Descrição não é necessária."), Category("Appearance")> ' Categoria da propriedade
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
Public Property MyProperties_Parent As Class_Child
```

Comment: Obrigado por me tentar ajudar, mas o resultado foi o mesmo, ou seja ficou como uma propriedade que parece estar em ReadOnly e não se expande.

Comment: Tente colocar o atributo <Browsable(True)> em cada membro público de `Class_Child`. Pode ser que funcione.

Comment: Acontece o mesmo assim, mas eu descobri outra forma de resolver o problema.